# EXT JS proxy throwing error

Tags: json, rest, extjs, proxy, extjs4.2

The following proxy has been throwing `listener` exceptions at sporadic moments. I added a `timeout:100` to try and recreate the error and it successfully throws it every time.

However the error sometimes occurs for a request under the [default](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest.html) of 30 seconds.

Is there anything else, besides the timeout, that would cause the `listener` exceptions to be thrown? There is nothing informative in the error logs.

```
proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: '/data/identity',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                successProperty: 'success',
                messageProperty: 'message'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: true
            },
            listeners: { 
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts){
                    if(operation.action === "read"){
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error Retrieving', response.responseText);
                    }else if(operation.action === "create"){
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error Creating', response.responseText);
                    }else if(operation.action === "update"){
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error Updating', response.responseText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `operation` object contains information about the error. It has a method `getError()` to get a description of the error. This would probably show you the error message you are looking for :

```
var error = operation.getError()
if(error.status && error.statusText){
    Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Error ' + error.status + ': ' + error.statusText)
}
```

This is the code I use in my proxy. In addition to display the error thrown during the `operation`, it also displays any error that happened on the server side (I catch them and send them in the `msg` property of the json data). The reason why I check for `navigator.onLine` is that my application uses Application Cache.

```
listeners: {
    exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
        var error = operation.getError(),
        errorMsg;
        if(!navigator.onLine){
            errorMsg = Lang._('You are not connected to internet.')
        } else if(Ext.isObject(error)){
            if(error.status && error.statusText)
                errorMsg = 'Error ' + error.status + ': ' + error.statusText
            else
                errorMsg = Ext.encode(error)
        } else if(response.responseText) {
            var json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            errorMsg = json.msg
        }
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: Lang._('Error loading external data'),
            msg: errorMsg,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        })
    }
}
```